# View logs from yesterday/today

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep, sh

I'm looking for a way to view multiple log files for the last two days into a single pass.

At first, I tried with GREP:

```
#!/bin/bash

yesterday=$(date --date="yesterday" +"%Y-%m-%d")
today=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
grep "$yesterday\|$today" *.log | less
```

This is nice but it doesn't output lines in between matches (lines that don't have the date in them, like error stack traces - which is what I'm really interested in)...

So I found this:

```
#!/bin/bash

yesterday=$(date --date="yesterday" +"%Y-%m-%d")
sed -ne '/$yesterday/,$p' *.log | less
```

For each file, it outputs everything from the first match to the end of the file.  That's just perfect... except for one thing... When reading it, I don't know which file's content I'm looking at.  I would like to see the file name at the start of each line, just like with a grep.

- How can I prefix the file name to each line in my sed command?
- Would there be a nicer / better way to do this?

Thanks ;-)

Comment: Check this: http://www.tecmint.com/view-multiple-files-in-linux/

Comment: you miss the essential. what are your logs format (sample)

Comment: I think you should use a `for` and prefix the filename with `echo`. Also, notice `sed` treats its arguments as a single continuous long stream so, in your example, I think that's not what you want (you could pass the `--separate` option if available).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a `sed` solution but as you asked for *a nicer / better way to do this*... If you have GNU awk somewhere,

```
awk -v day="$yesterday" 'BEGINFILE {run=0} $0 ~ day {run=1} run == 1 {print FILENAME, $0}' *.log
```

should make it.

**Explanation:**

GNU awk processes all files in sequence. The GNU awk variable `day` is initialized to the shell expression `"$yesterday"` GNU awk executes the `BEGINFILE` rule before processing a new file. This rule clears the `run` variable. Whenever a line (`$0`) matches GNU awk variable `day` (`"$yesterday"`) the `run` variable is set. And when the `run` variable is set, the name of the current file is printed (`FILENAME`), followed by the current line (`$0`).

Comment: I'm answering a little late, but I have been using your solution for a while now and it works great! Thanks ;-)